# Understanding fmap with a monad

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have the following data type:

```
newtype Rep f a = Rep { runRep :: String -> f (String, a) }
```

The above type `Rep f a` is a stateful computation that takes a `String` as the initial state and produces a `(String, a)` as the result of the computation. `f` is a functor and the result of the computation is wrapped in the functor.

For the following function.

```
rep :: Functor f => Rep f a -> String -> f a
rep a s = fmap snd (runRep a s)
```

This function can be used to run a "Rep" computation on a string. However, I am not sure why runRep has to take a `Rep f a` as input as well as a `String`.
Further for the line `fmap snd (runRep a s)`, I am not sure whether the second element of the tuple will be returned wrapped in the functor or without it.

Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`runRep` is something you defined in your record:

```
newtype Rep f a = Rep { runRep :: String -> f (String, a) }
```

The compiler will automatically construct a "getter" function for that with the name `runRep`. Such getter has the signature:

```
someGetter :: Record -> TypeOfField
```

For your `runRep`, it is thus:

```
runRep :: Rep f a -> (String -> f (String, a))
```

or less verbose:

```
runRep :: Rep f a -> String -> f (String, a)
```

The `runRep` is thus a function that indeed takes a `Rep f a`, and returns a function that takes a `String` and returns an `f (String, a)`.

> I am not sure whether the second element of the tuple will be returned wrapped in the functor or without it.

You will perform an `fmap snd` on the `f (String, a)`. `fmap snd` has as signature:

```
fmap snd :: Functor f => f (a, b) -> f b
```

So you can indeed state that it will return the second item of the data wrapped in the functor. Although "wrapped" might not be the best word here.

Note that if `f ~ []`, then you map on a list of 2-tuples, and you thus will return a list of all second items of that list.